# Car revs high around (2-4k rpm) when idle then goes back to normal, also accelerating on its own while driving

Tags: engine, manual-transmission, gasoline, acceleration, rev-limiter

I'm new to this website and hoping to seek some answers about my problem this past years. My car is Kia Avella quite an old car but still in good condition (i guess)

The problem happened a year ago when i try to start the car left it for about 5 minutes then i noticed the car revs on its own without applying gas tried checking the gas pedal if it's stuck somehow or the gas cable but no problem either, then suddenly the car goes back to normal idle rpm is back to normal. I tried test driving it all went good but after few minutes it was revving high again and this time with unintended acceleration, it's like someone was stepping on the gas and the car run few meters the goes back to normal. after that i drive the car normal for the span of that day but still the problem was still there and i know that it would happen again tomorrow.

I forgot to mention that it happens every morning when i start the car to warm it up. Hoping to see some answers. Thanks.

Comment: I think I would start be looking for vacuum leaks (they could be intermittent) and also check the operation of the IAC Idle Air Control or "Idle Speed" system.

Comment: It would help to know the year & engine size of the Kia.

Comment: Thanks for the replies, i will try checking those IAC idle air control or idle speed system @SteveRacer

Comment: @Pᴀᴜʟsᴛᴇʀ2♦ My Kia Avella yr model is 2004 about the engine size i don't know where and how to check it.